# The app didnt start in required time WIndows-10

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am trying to port my Windows Phone 8 app to Windows 10. I am able to build my app. When I try to deploy my app in **Release x86** on a Mobile emulator I hit this error: [Symbols for "ntdll.dll" could not be downloaded from Microsoft Symbol Servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979342/symbols-for-ntdll-dll-could-not-be-downloaded-from-microsoft-symbol-servers)

Hence I am trying to run without Debugging. In VS-2015 **Debug->Start Without Debugging** (in **Release** mode for **x86**), I get this error when I use Mobile Emulator:

> Unable to activate Windows Store App 'XXXX'. The activation request failed with error "**The app didn't start in the required time**".

I created a Blank Universal Windows project. I am not sure, why VS is considering this as a Windows Store App.

I followed these steps: **File->New->Project->Templates->Visual C#->Windows->Universal->Blank App(Universal Windows)**

Comment: Does this happen with any app, or just this app? (Try a blank app for example). Is there code in the startup that could be causing it? Is the app really large?

Comment: Hi @WiredPrairie, Thanks a lot for response. The issue seems only with my app. I can run samples from here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples
On further debugging the issue with my app, I see this message in the event log:"App for the Windows.Launch contract failed with error: The remote procedure call failed..".

Comment: Hi @WiredPrairie, This old msdn page:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fb34424-655f-4ff2-bd9b-d52fe12ff61f/windowslaunch-contract-failed-with-error-the-remote-procedure-call-failed?forum=winappswithcsharp talks about this issue. But the solution on that page is to get a valid dev license for Windows Store apps. Do I need anything similar for Windows-10 apps as well? I mean is there a separate license for Windows-10 app like the Store app used to have?

Comment: To do Win 10 development, you should already have gotten the license (I believe Visual Studio forces the issue when you first create a new project).

Comment: And -- I don't have the emulator installed anymore, but is trying to deploy with x86 the right option? What is the default when you create a new Windows Store app?

Comment: Hi @WiredPrairie, Thanks for your response. Yeah, VS-2015 has Release/Debug options for ARM/x86/x64 architectures. With WIndows-10 do we still have concept of Windows Store apps? I assume moving forward everything would be Universal Windows apps

Comment: Yes, it should be a universal app.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the Microsoft symbol server set, so the debugger is trying to download the .pdb's for all the publically available .dll's in your app to step through them. Try disabling the symbol server and some other options to get past this:

[image]

It's timing out trying to download the symbols and that's causing the debugger to time out. Also, try enabling Just My Code and see if that lets the debugger skip these binaries that you probably don't want to step through:

[image]

Comment: Hi @MichaelBraude, Thanks for the response. I actually have these settings in my VS-2015, still I am unable to deploy my app on the emulator. The hit the "App didn't start in the required time" in-spite of these settings.

Comment: Ok, but is it trying to load the pdbs any more? The emulator could just take a long gone on your machine. Try launching the emulator before you deploy so it's already up.

Comment: Hi @MichaelBraude, Thanks for the response. I have a Intel Core i7, 3.6GHz with 16GB RAM. So machine maynot be the problem. I do not see any more .pdb's being loaded.